# Priority of aliases files for Drush

Tags: 8, drush

I have an installation with lando. On the project, we have a directory drush with an aliases file for the project. This file defines aliases with the root specific for the lando architecture.

In my home directory, I have an aliases file in my .drush directory with the same name which define the same aliases but with a root different, specific for my local computer, outside from lando.

Both aliases files are detect by drush but the problem, the aliases file from the project is always take in priority, inside or outside from lando. But outside lando, files are never find like the root isn't correct.

The weird thing is my colleagues haven't had this problem and the root is aliases file is correctly choice when they are outside from lando. We're thinking we have forgotten a configuration somewhere but we don't see what.

I'm using Drush 8.2.3, my colleagues are using Drush 8.1.16. I could downgrade the Drush version but this will delay the problem.

Someone has an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: The version of Drush is quite relevant to provide a good answer - please add that to your post. You might also indicate what version of Drupal by using the 8 tag.

Comment: Indeed, we think this is related too. I added the precision.

Comment: In fact, we think drush 8.2.x take aliases in the drush directory in priority like it should be the case with drush 9.